# What's wrong with my MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I've followed the syntax guide for creating tables exactly how it should be but I keep getting a syntax error. Can someone help me out?

```
$createQuery = sprintf("CREATE TABLE %s(message_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, message TEXT, sender TEXT, recipient TEXT, PRIMARY KEY( message_ID )) ENGINE=MyISAM;",$tablename);
$createResult = mysqli_query($connect, $createQuery);
```

$tablename in this case is 1-3

Comment: I seem to remember that '-' isn't a valid character for an identifier when unescaped.  Does it work for other $tablename?

Comment: I ran the query, it works just fine. The problem is indeed the table name which is invalid without the indicating that it's a string.

Comment: Yeah the problem is fixed now. I had to add `%s`. Thanks to JakeGould and user3678068

Comment: @JakeGould checked your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding back ticks to the `%s`:

```
$createQuery = sprintf("CREATE TABLE `%s` (message_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, message TEXT, sender TEXT, recipient TEXT, PRIMARY KEY( message_ID )) ENGINE=MyISAM;",$tablename);
$createResult = mysqli_query($connect, $createQuery);
```

Also your original code had the `%s` right next to the parenthesis `(`. Technically with back ticks, that should not be an issue, but you should get in the habit of just adding spaces between things when dealing with MySQL queries.

That said, you could also achieve the same results without `sprintf()` by just placing `$tablename` directly into the code because double-quotes allow for string substitution:

```
$createQuery = "CREATE TABLE `$tablename` (message_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, message TEXT, sender TEXT, recipient TEXT, PRIMARY KEY( message_ID )) ENGINE=MyISAM;";
$createResult = mysqli_query($connect, $createQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your tablename like so

```
$tablename = '`1-3`';
```